# Как отключить сообщение "Завершить принудительно" "Подождать" в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, 1с, gtk

Собственно весь subj в теме. Ubuntu 18.04.2
Во время отладки в 1С, когда остановился на точке останова, через некоторе время (5-6 секунд) иногда быстрее и иногда очень часто поверх отлаживаемого приложения появляется модальное сообщение, которое блокирует весь интерфейс системы, предлагая выбрать одно из двух: ждать или завершить. Приходится иногда по десятку раз ткнуть в "подождать" прежде чем в отладчике получается просмотреть значения переменных или перейти на другую строку. Можно как то отключить это всплывающее сообщение? Либо его сделать не модальным.

Comment: скорее всего можно. главное — знать, какой процесс рисует это окно. но тут всё только в ваших руках.

Comment: по идее его выводит оконный менеджер... ЕМНИП в новых бубунтах — это mutter... и судя по всему это поведение и таймаут не настраиваются и [захардкожены](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412917/how-to-increase-waiting-time-for-non-responding-programs), так что если кратко — ни как... если подробней, то можно пересобрать mutter с патчиком или использовать другие WM/DE...